cannot get finnhub npm library to work properly
the function getSymbolPrice works fine and returns
Quote {
  o: 602.715,
  h: 607.99,
  l: 599.2849,
  c: 607.75,
  pc: 599.85,
  d: 7.9,
  dp: 1.317
}

but other functions do nothing

getMarketStatus logs null


getMarketStatus logs nothing

here is my code picked up mostly from finnhub docs
require("dotenv").config();
const finnhub = require("finnhub");

const api_key = finnhub.ApiClient.instance.authentications["api_key"];
api_key.apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
const finnhubClient = new finnhub.DefaultApi();

async function getSymbolPrice(symbol) {
  try {
    finnhubClient.quote(symbol, (err, data, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error -> ", error);
  }
}

async function listSymbols(market) {
  try {
    finnhubClient.stockSymbols(market, (error, data, response) => {
      console.log("Stock Symbols Data:", data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error ->", error);
  }
}

async function getMarketStatus(market) {
  try {
    finnhubClient.marketStatus({'exchange': market}, (error, data, response) => {
      console.log(data)
    });      
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

getSymbolPrice("META");
getMarketStatus("US");
listSymbols("US");

